Linux virtual machine boot taking way too long on refurbished windows 10 host
I have an Ubuntu VM that I mostly use as a Samba server. My host is a refurbished Dell laptop (Core I7) that seems to have seen heavy use , so I'm assuming portions of the SSD have been rendered useless (just a wild guess not too sure although I am assuming it has some problems as it even buffers keyboard characters every once in a while).
I am looking for ways to confirm said issues on the host and how these problems would manifest themselves during linux boot. Here's the relevant dmesg.
Would love to know what I could do to speed up VM boot. Additionally, would appreciate tips on how I could use native windows tools like perfmon and resource monitor to narrow down issue on the windows host side. PerfMon shows a lot of disk transfers which is confirmed by the resource monitor. In addition, I see a lot of memory thrashing (hard faults) on resource monitor. Plus Maximum frequency fluctuates betweek 100% to 87% (never goes down below 87%).
Or could this be an issue with the memory?
Update 1:
a) System specs:
13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1365U, 1.80 GHz, 16GB RAM
b) at 6GB RAM and 2 vCPUs, it took a total of 2 min, 7s for the login screen to appear.
Update 2:
Here's the output of journalctl -b. I see a bunch of errors related to systemd. I wonder if disabling some unnecessary services would help.

How much spare RAM do you have?

Btw there is like at least 14 generations of "Core i7", and among each there's like different "target level". And by slow how long do you mean exactly? Like 30s slow or 3min slow?

Also you may want to share journalctl -b output instead. It seems that further "boot up related" logs have been redirected to journald after it started at 90s? On the other hand, there is indeed a 28s gap before piix4_smbus 0000:00:07.3: SMBus Host Controller not enabled!...

@grawity_u1686 16 GB

@TomYan updated my question with further details, esp the output of journalctl. Apparently, some services are failing

@Skegg I don't seem to see that it being particular slow as per the timestamps. Are you experiencing / witnessing any stalling in particular? (I mean like if so, where exactly does it stall it? And for how long? Some boot splash? Or after you have entered your password on the DM?)
